# How to count product in this category?

Tags: mysql, count, product

How to count product in this category?

TABLE CATEGORY

```
category_id 
title 
lft 
rght 
parent 
level
```

TABLE PRODUCT

```
product_id 
category_id 
title
```

DATA
Table category

```
|1|Electronics|1|16|0|0
|2|Televisions|2|7|1|1
|3|LCD|3|4|2|2
|4|PLASMA|5|6|2|2
|5|Players|8|15|1|1
|6|Mp3 players|9|10|5|2
|7|CD players|11|12|5|2
|8|DVD players|13|14|5|2
|9|Furniture|17|18|0|0
```

Table product

```
|1|4|Plasma 1
|2|4|Plasma 2
|3|4|Plasma 3
|4|4|Plasma 4
|5|4|Plasma 5
|6|3|LCD 1
|7|3|LCD 2
|8|3|LCD 3
|9|6|MP3 1
|10|6|MP3 2
|11|7|CD 1
|12|7|CD 2
|13|8|DVD 1
|14|8|DVD 2
|15|8|DVD 3
```

I would like to count these example.

```
Electronics (15)
Televisions (8)
LCD (3)
PLASMA (5)
Players (7)
Mp3 players (2)
CD players (2)
DVD players (3)
Furniture (0)
```

and use

SQL

```
select parent.title, parent.level, count(product.title) as sum_products  
from category as node, category as parent, product  
where node.lft between parent.lft and parent.rght   
and node.category_id = product.category_id  
group by parent.title   
order by node.lft
```

and these result

```
Electronics (15)
Televisions (8)
LCD (3)
PLASMA (5)
Players (7)
Mp3 players (2)
CD players (2)
DVD players (3)
```

How I'll make out like a sample?

Furniture (0) Don't show in query.

Thank you for your help.

> select parent.title, parent.level, coalesce(count(product.title),0) as
>   sum_products from category as node, category as parent, product where
>   node.lft between parent.lft and parent.rght and node.category_id =
>   product.category_id group by parent.title order by node.lft

https://i.stack.imgur.com/adJd2.png

Thank you jpw for answer

This code complete

```
select 
  parent.title, 
  parent.level, 
  count(product.title) as sum_products  
from category as node
join category as parent 
  on node.lft between parent.lft and parent.rght   
left join product 
  on node.category_id = product.category_id  
group by parent.title, parent.level
order by node.lft

|       TITLE | LEVEL | SUM_PRODUCTS |
|-------------|-------|--------------|
| Electronics |     0 |           15 |
| Televisions |     1 |            8 |
|         LCD |     2 |            3 |
|      PLASMA |     2 |            5 |
|     Players |     1 |            7 |
| Mp3 players |     2 |            2 |
|  CD players |     2 |            2 |
| DVD players |     2 |            3 |
|   Furniture |     0 |            0 |
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to achieve. If you're trying to count the number of products in a category, I think you've got it.

The only difference I'm seeing is that Furniture doesn't show up because there aren't any records.

You could try using `coalesce(count(product.title),0) as sum_products` to give empty results a 0 as a default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the problem is that the empty category furniture is excluded I believe a solution is to use an explicit left join instead of the implicit inner join to the product table like this:

```
select 
  parent.title, 
  parent.level, 
  count(product.title) as sum_products  
from category as node
join category as parent 
  on node.lft between parent.lft and parent.rght   
left join product 
  on node.category_id = product.category_id  
group by parent.title, parent.level
order by node.lft
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a83e3/3)

This query would give the following output:

```
|       TITLE | LEVEL | SUM_PRODUCTS |
|-------------|-------|--------------|
| Electronics |     0 |           15 |
| Televisions |     1 |            8 |
|         LCD |     2 |            3 |
|      PLASMA |     2 |            5 |
|     Players |     1 |            7 |
| Mp3 players |     2 |            2 |
|  CD players |     2 |            2 |
| DVD players |     2 |            3 |
|   Furniture |     0 |            0 |
```

Comment: @Aunz HzOnos you should accept his answer if it solved your question

Comment: @AunzHzOnos You're welcome. The preferred way to indicate that an answer solved the problem is to mark it as accepted. Doing so rewards a bit of reputation to both the answerer and you, and it lets the system (and community) know that the question has been resolved in a satisfactory manner. :)