# How to Query product when search with parent id?

Tags: php, mysql

> refer to
>
> [How to count product in this category?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28194143/how-to-count-product-in-this-category)
>
> TABLE CATEGORY

```
 category_id  
 title 
 lft 
 rght 
 parent 
 level
```

> TABLE PRODUCT

```
 product_id 
 category_id 
 title
```

> DATA Table category
>
> ```
> |1|Electronics|1|16|0|0
> |2|Televisions|2|7|1|1
> |3|LCD|3|4|2|2
> |4|PLASMA|5|6|2|2
> |5|Players|8|15|1|1
> |6|Mp3 players|9|10|5|2
> |7|CD players|11|12|5|2
> |8|DVD players|13|14|5|2
> |9|Furniture|17|18|0|0
> ```

if i want to query product to show all i will query in table product

```
SELECT * from product order by product_id
```

but if i want to query by parent id How will i query?

i tried to query

```
select product.*
from category as node, category as parent, product  
where node.lft between parent.lft and parent.rght   
and node.category_id = product.category_id  
group by parent.title   
order by node.lft
```

but Does not meet the requirements.

if i will to search Televisions category_id = 2
I want to show product in category_id 2 same example

```
Example
|1|4|Plasma 1
|2|4|Plasma 2
|3|4|Plasma 3
|4|4|Plasma 4
|5|4|Plasma 5
|6|3|LCD 1
|7|3|LCD 2
|8|3|LCD 3
```

Please help me.
Thank you for the answers.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2kxzt.png  img DATA in Table category

Comment: what are the fields in "DATA Table category" how is it related with other two?

Comment: why are your left and right values greater than the Category Id?  I would assume that the Left and Right indicate the CategoryId values...  the data doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/2kxzt.png this data in table category

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have no possibility to debug that, and have no idea what is your `lft` and `rgth` for.

But to get result you need, you can try:

```
SELECT product.*
from product
LEFT JOIN category as cat 
ON product.category_id = cat.category_id 
WHERE cat.parent = 2
```